# How to format randomly sampled list elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to get the following output:

```
T1: j2 
T2: j4
T3: j3
T1: j7
T2: j
T3: j6
T1: j5
```

I have tried it with a for loop but I am not able to do it. This is my code:

```
import random

team = ['t1','t2','t3']
task = ["j","j2","j3","j4","j5","j6","j7"]

print (task)
s_task = random.sample(task,len(task))
print (s_task)

for itm in team:
    for itm1 in s_task:
        print(itm,itm1)

T1: j2 
T2: j4
T3: j3
T1: j7
T2: j
T3: j6
T1: j5
```

Comment: how can you know the output if you are using random?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read through [ask], especially the part about introducing the problem before posting any code.

Comment: I mean i just need the format, sure it will change every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need `itertools.cycle` and `random.choice`

**Ex:**

```
import random
from itertools import cycle
team = ['t1','t2','t3']
task = ["j","j2","j3","j4","j5","j6","j7"]


team = cycle(team)
for _ in range(len(task)):
    print("{}: {}".format(next(team), random.choice(task)))
```

**Output:**

```
t1: j5
t2: j5
t3: j
t1: j7
t2: j6
t3: j7
t1: j3
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just need a way to format your output, you could use:

[Formatted string literal](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) aka f-string (for Python 3.6 or later) like

```
for itm in team:
    for itm1 in s_task:
        print(f"{itm}: {itm1}")
```

Read more about f-strings [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

---

If your Python3 is lower than Python3.6, stick with [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and use

```
print("{}: {}".format(itm, itm1))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [string.format()](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
import random

team = ['t1','t2','t3']
task = ["j","j2","j3","j4","j5","j6","j7"]

print (task)
s_task = random.sample(task,len(task))
print (s_task)

for itm in team:
    for itm1 in s_task:
        print("{}: {}".format(itm,itm1))
```

This should print in yout required format

Answer (score 0):

Using concatenation,

```
print(itm, ": ", itm1)
```

Using Old String formatting,

```
print("%s: %s"%(itm, itm1))
```

Using New string formating,

```
print("{0}: {1}".format(itm, itm1))


import random

team = ['t1','t2','t3']
task = ["j","j2","j3","j4","j5","j6","j7"]

print (task)
s_task = random.sample(task,len(task))
print (s_task)

for itm in team:
    for itm1 in s_task:
        print(itm, ": ", itm1)

T1: j2 
T2: j4
T3: j3
T1: j7
T2: j
T3: j6
T1: j5
```

Comment: `print(itm, ": ", itm1)` This will intercalate spaces in between the arguments. Adding the optional keyword arg produces the desired output though: `print(..., sep='')`.